# Couldn't upgrade SQL Server localDB to 2022 version

Tags: sql-server

So I have downloaded and installed SQL Server 2022 Express
but im still getting Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (15.0.4153.1) when checking with command
`sqllocaldb versions`.
Ive also tried creating new instance
`sqllocaldb create "mydb" 16.0`
and im getting this error
**"Creation of LocalDB instance "mydb" failed because of the following error: The specified LocalDB version is not available on this computer."**

Comment: Check your `PATH` environment variable

Comment: Hi this is the PATH environment variable https://ibb.co/rm4nbkY

Answer (score 1):

Ive Solved the problem by following this page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16
run SQL2022-SSEI-Expr.exe file then choice download media and click localdb on the specified download location you will see a file called SqlLocalDB.msi run and and install
thats it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The installer just downloads it from here BTW https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/d/38de7036-2433-4207-8eae-06e247e17b25/SqlLocalDB.msi